# How to get Select2 v4.0 object from ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-select2

I have a little javascript

```
$(".tags").select2({
tags: true,
createTag: function(params) { 
    var select2_object = $(this).parent();
    $.get($(this).parent().parent().data('url'), function(data) {
        return {
            id: 'new_' + params.term,
            text: params.term
        };
   });  
},
```

});

In the createTag function I will create a new record in the database via ajax. But ajax url is set dynamically from data attributes. So I need access to Select2 data attributes.

var select2_object did not return to me proper Select2 object.

In wich way I can get the Select2 jQuery object?

Answer (score 1):

check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4uqwonjx/1/)

```
<select multiple="true" name="tags[]" id="tagSelector" class="select2" data-url="URL HERE">
    <option value="1">Value1</option>
    <option value="2">Value2</option>
    <option value="3">Value2</option>
</select>

$('.select2').select2({
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [",", " "]
}).on("change", function(e) {
    alert($(this).data('url'));
    var _new = $(this).find('[data-select2-tag="true"]');
    if (_new.length) {
        _new.replaceWith('<option selected value="' + _new.val() + '">' + _new.val() + '</option>');
    }
});
```